# How can I ignore a package dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install `mssql-server` on Ubuntu;

I did all [these steps on microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017).

And I get the message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: openssl (<= 1.1.0)
```

But I already have `openssl=1.1.0g-2ubuntu4`, and i think that is OK to go with this version of `openssl`. How can I skip this check?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is this you try this on?

Comment: @Videonauth that is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Well i guess you got an already working for you answer right now?

Comment: @Videonauth now it provides conflicts, so it was removed with  `apt-get --fix-broken`, I will reinstall it later.

Comment: O.k. when you do, please provide any maybe showing up conflicts by doing an [edit] of your question then, so either I can write you an answer or the current answerer can update his. As far i can see the biggest problem is, that this package was made for Ubuntu 16.04 and that there is no package yet for 18.04.

Comment: @Videonauth I tried to install mono after I have intalled mssql-server, and all packages that require openssl were flagged to require <= 1.1.0 version. Console output suggested to do a fix. If there someway to mask the package it will be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft did not update their package MSSQL. Since openssl has got important fixes recently I would not try to ignore the dependency.

I recommend to install `mysql-server` instead of mssql.

If you still want to install mssql this is the way to go:

`apt download mssql-server`

`dpkg --ignore-depends=openssl -i mssql-server.deb`

Comment: sudo apt-get install mssql-server --nodeps

Comment: or       --no-install-recommends

Comment: With `--no-install-recommends` I get the same erroneous output, it seems like it does nothing. `--nodeps` flag is not available.

Comment: apt download mssql-server  then dpkg --ignore-depends=openssl -i mssql-server.deb  . replace the mssql-server.deb with the filename that the apt downloads.